# Want to call magento2 rest api from react js

Tags: magento2, react

I am creating 1 application in react and have a requirement to call magento api from react js

My magento application is hosted on http://localserver.com and react is with http://localhost:3000/

Below is my code in react

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localffc.com/rest/V1/directory/areas/AE")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result
        });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>

            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}  

export default App;
```

But I am getting below error

Access to fetch at 'http://localserver.com/rest/V1/directory/areas/AE' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Please help me how i can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I go the solution

Go to your site config file for example

nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/localmagento.com.conf

and add

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/
 ServerName localmagento.com
 ServerAlias www.localmagento.com
 <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and use a2enmod headers and then restart server.